# How to prevent a popup windows to open in other pages after closing

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I've made a popup promo window that open after 5 second that a page is loaded.
However, after a visitor has clicked on "close", I would like to prevent that the popup show again let's say for 120 minutes.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <div class="popup">
        <button id="close">&times;</button>
        <h2>This Is The Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita distinctio fugiat alias iure qui, commodi minima magni ullam aliquam dignissimos?</p>
        <a href="#">Let's Go</a>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    setTimeout(
        function open(event){
            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "block";
        },
        2000
    )
});


document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Use sessionStorage / localStorage